# (Symfony) join two table without relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms, php-5.5

**Between my entities there is no relation**

In my page web i have two related drop down list by using Ajax. for the first one i have different titles, my table is like this: Title(title_id , title). this is my code for display the titles in the drop down which is in my controller

```
$title = $em->getRepository('...Bundle:Title')->findAll();
$MesTitle = array();
foreach ( $title as $une) {
    $MesTitle[ $une->getTitleid() ]=  $une->getTitle();
}

$formTitle->add("title", "choice", 
    array(
        "label" => "Title" ,
        'empty_value' => 'select your Title',
        "choices" =>$MesTitle
    )
);
```

for the second one when user chooses one title we must to show him the subtitle of the title Selected, for this i have two tables: The first one HasTitle( title_id , sub_title_id) and second on SubTitle(sub_title_id , sub_title).for this i'm using AJAX and this is my code:

```
$('#title_title').change(function() {
    var titleid = $("#title_title option:selected").val();
    console.log(titleid);
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'http://localhost:.../.../web/app_dev.php/....../',
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log('cooll');
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }   
    });
});
```

I need a method in my controller wich take `$title_id` from JS(AJAX) and give me the value of `sub_title` for display them in the second drop down.

**Between my entities there is no relation**

Thank you

Comment: Sorry what is Symphony ? :o

Comment: It's a common mistake to write _Symphony_ instead of _Symfony_ . Plus, [Symphony is an existing CMS](http://www.getsymphony.com/).

Comment: I'm so sorry, it was a mistake a misspelling

Comment: I'm new in symfony, could you help me

Comment: I hope my explanation was clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form events with symfony form and jquery.
When you submit the form with the value of the first select you need to load the values in the second one. In the Symfony website you can see an example with sports.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

You need create a event for the first select.
Regards.